# Div Showing Up At Incorrect Location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I have a  that contains two nested div's.  One of the nested div's  contains a javascript graph.

When the page renders, the javascript graph is at an incorrect location, outside of the 's area.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Here are the css:

```
#graph_container{
  width: 75%;   
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin-top: 20px; 
}

#graph{
  width: 75%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#car_select{
  width: 25%;   
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

And Rails.ERB file

```
<div id="graph_container">
  <div id="car_select"> 
  # this part is at the correct location...     
  </div>

  <div id = "graph">
  # this is showing up outside of graph_container
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
    //<![CDATA[
    var chart = new AnyChart('/AnyChart.swf'); 
    chart.width = 500; 
    chart.height = 500; 
    chart.setXMLFile('car_info.xml'); 
    chart.write(); 
    //]]> 
    </script> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pat and Danny's suggestions were valid and important for the output.  But neither fixed my problem, what turned out to be the issue was actually the Javascript code.  I didn't set where the  code was suppose to be inserted.

Simply placing  within the  element I wanted DID NOT work.  In my case, what I needed to do was fill in chart.write() with chart.write('graph'), so that the script would insert itself in the  part of the html.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `<div>`s in the right place with 2 fixes:

1. Float them left and right respectively.
2. Add a clearing element below them so they stay inside the #graph_container.

You can see it [in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/gvVND/).

If that doesn't work, your Javascript may be setting the position on the graph it creates to absolute. In this case, add `position: relative;` to your #graph container.  This will cause any absolutely positioned children (i.e. the graph) to use it, rather than the document, as its coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the positioning absolute?

http://cssdesk.com/EUYhZ